# How to force Django to use select2 from the CDN instead of the local admin version?

Tags: javascript, django, function, django-templates, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement a website using `Django`. I have used `select2` as one of my components. My problem is that when rendering the template, Django is using `select2` from `admin` which lives here: [Click here to go to GitHub code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/aff7a58aef0264e5b2740e5df07894ecc0d7a580/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/vendor/select2/select2.full.js). I want to use `select2` loaded from the CDN because it is newer and also I want to pass extra parameters.

Here is my code (I removed unnecessary parts to make it simpler):

**core/templates/core/base.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**app_name/templates/app_name/template_name.html:**

```html
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <div class="input-group input-group-lg col-12">
                <select id="id_select2" class="form-control selectpicker" name="options[]"
                        multiple="multiple" data-live-search="true">
                    <option data-tokens="123" value="456">Test</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#id_select2').select2();
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I know that this problem is caused because of having two functions with exactly the same name and parameters.

Comment: Try to load the select2 script just before you create your <script> tag in your html

Comment: I'm really grad ! I gonna put it in an answer and you can mark it as solving answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to put the import of select2 (the script) inside the body of the html, just before your own script tag

:D